# Which lib can develop a console application which can input in the bottom and print information on the interface in C#

Tags: c#, console

I want to develop a console application which has a fixed input position for me to input command while the information can be printed above it.
It is just like a Minecraft Server Console.
[image: screen]

Comment: You can explicitly set Cursor positions... if that helps. [Console.CursorLeft Property](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.console.cursorleft?view=net-8.0), [Console.CursorTop Property](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.console.cursortop?view=net-8.0)

Comment: Well, nobody is going to write a full solution for you.   You might want to rephrase your question to ask for hints into the right direction - as to which libraries to use.   On GNU / Linux, ncurses is generally used for these tasks - not sure whether there are any .NET bindings for it.

Comment: @MartinBaulig Like this:  https://github.com/MV10/dotnet-curses ?

Comment: @MartinBaulig Maybe not

Comment: @Fildor It may work, but I cannot clear the command that I input which will be printed in the screen, too.

Comment: Maybe this would be useful? https://github.com/gui-cs/Terminal.Gui.

Comment: _"but I cannot clear the command"_ - yes, you have to explicitly overwrite with whitespace, unfortunately.